# how to show pagination links in resource laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, pagination, resources

I have a resource in this resource I have collection , now I want to show the pagination links of that collection, how can I do it?

This is my resource

```
public function toArray($request)
{


    return [
        "name"              =>  $this->name ,
        "slug"              =>  $this->slug ,
        "bg_image"          =>  imageGenerate("sections" , $this->bg_image) ,
        "bg_color"          =>  $this->bg_color ,
        "items"             =>  new ItemCollection($this->items()->paginate(20)) ,
    ];
}
```

this is my collection

```
public function toArray($request)
{

    return $this->collection->map(function ($item) {
        return [
            "id"            =>  $item->id ,
            "name"          =>  $item->name ,
            "slug"          =>  $item->slug ,
            "image"         =>  imageGenerate("items" , $item->image) ,
            "code"          =>  $item->code ,
            "category"      =>  $item->category->name??""
        ];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel 8.x documentation, you may pass in the data that you want paginate to newly created Collection instance. Here is an example:

```
use App\Http\Resources\UserCollection;
use App\Models\User;

Route::get('/users', function () {
    return new UserCollection(User::paginate());
});
```

Also see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#pagination)